# no matching constructor for initialization of 'std::map<char, char []>' c++11

Tags: c++, dictionary, c++11, initialization

i am trying to initialize the following map in c++11

```
#include <map>
std::map<char, const char []> nomi = {
    { (char) 0, "Oggetto" },
    { (char) 1, "Entity" },
    { (char) 2, "Player" },
    { (char) 3, "Proiettile" },
    { (char) 4, "SaltoInAlto" },
    { (char) 5, "SuperVelocita" },
    { (char) 6, "Volo" },
    { (char) 7, "Pavimento" }
};
```

if i use previous versions i get different errors since i can't initialize this way a map...
so i am using -std=c++11

Comment: I would use std::string instead.

Comment: i can't, it is required i use cost char []

Comment: Use const char* then.

Comment: it seems to work... i still don't understand why but thank u

Comment: The bracket syntax to actually specify pointers is only valid for *function parameters* – and there only the *outer-most dimension*. Anywhere else brackets mean true arrays, but your map declaration leaves the array length unspecified. How should the compiler know how many bytes to allocate for one map entry then?

Comment: One further problem is that you actually need to create `std::pair`s containing arrays – and for these you need to call a constructor, but that one would result in an assignment (note: not initialisation!) like `char const array[64]; array = "...";` (initialisation: `char const array[] = "..."` with array size deduced from initialiser!). So even if you provided the necessary size using the initialiser list would not work.

Comment: [Play around](https://godbolt.org/z/bGj3h153E) a bit...

Comment: You are in C++ so use `std::map<char, std::string>` or if you are sure life time of all strings is infinitive use: `std::map<char, std::string_view>` . Anyway if key type is `char` maybe `std::array` is more reasonable solution?

Comment: Btw. with your exposed code, `std::map` is the 2nd best choice. A `std::array` or `std::vector` allows access by keys 0, 1, 2, ... more efficient and without the need to store the keys. (The keys are called "index" in that case.)